# MemoryMappedViewStream error "does not have appropriate access"

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to create a MMF-backed collection that dynamically expands up to 2GB.  I wanted to be able to read existing items at the same time new items are being added.  It works great on my development machine but I am getting an error on some machines:

> The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

Has anyone seen this error before?  I am likely doing something wrong with the way I am handling MemoryMappedFiles, I'm creating a 2GB MMF with the DelayAllocatePages flag so it doesn't use it all right away:

```
public const long ONE_GIGABYTE = 1073741824;
long maxCapacity = 2 * ONE_GIGABYTE;
mmStorage = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(mmfName, maxCapacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, MemoryMappedFileOptions.DelayAllocatePages, null, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
```

Then I write data to it a chunk at a time, using an internal collection to keep track of where each chunk is located.

```
lock ( writeLock ) {
    // get the most recently added item
    var lastItem = _itemLocations[_itemLocations.Count - 1];
    // calculate next items offset
    long newOffset = lastItem.Offset + lastItem.Length;

    // add next items data
    using ( var mmStream = mmStorage.CreateViewStream(newOffset, itemBytes.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite) ) {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Writing {0} bytes at location {1}", itemBytes.Length, newOffset));
        mmStream.Write(itemBytes, 0, itemBytes.Length);
    }

    // add location info to list
    _itemLocations.Add(new ItemLocation()
    {
        Offset = newOffset,
        Length = itemBytes.Length
    });
}
```

On the remote machine the first write goes ok, but the second write is causing the exception I mentioned which kills the program completely.

> Writing 5973 bytes at location 0
>
> Writing 5901 bytes at location 5973
>
> The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

## Update

I have tried changing

`MemoryMappedFileOptions.DelayAllocatePages`

to

`MemoryMappedFileOptions.None`

and it stops throwing the exception, but it also allocates the full 2GB right away.  I'd prefer if I could grow the MMF as needed but I guess it wont work on all machines.  I'm not sure why `DelayAllocatePages` works on some machines and not others.

Comment: It is an AccessViolationException, the kind you should never see in a C# program.  My money is on lousy anti-malware screwing this up.

Comment: Thanks for putting a name to the exception, it always happens the second time I create a viewstream and try to write to it. (and it has to allocate more memory for my MMF behind the scenes)